# How to handle Rundeck kill job signal

Tags: rundeck

I have a Python script that is being executed via Rundeck. I already have implemented handlers for signal.SIGINT and signal.SIGTERM but when the script is terminated via Rundeck KILL JOB BUTTON it is not catching the signal.

Someone know what KILL BUTTON in Rundeck use under the woods to kills the process?

Example of how I'm catching signals, it works in a standard command line execution:

```
def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
    proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    children_procs = proc.children(recursive=True)
    children_procs.reverse()
    for child_proc in children_procs:
        try:
            if child_proc.is_running():
                msg = f'removing: {child_proc.pid}, 
                        {child_proc.name}'
                logging.debug(msg)
                os.kill(child_proc.pid, SIGINT)
        except OSError as exc:
            raise Error('Error removing processes', detail=str(exc))
    sys.exit(SIGINT_EXIT)
```

Adding debug logging level in Rundeck get this:

```
[wf:7bb0cd58-7dc6-4a55-bb0f-62399533396c] Interrupted: Engine interrupted, stopping engine...
Disconnecting from 9.11.56.44 port 22
[wf:7bb0cd58-7dc6-4a55-bb0f-62399533396c] WillShutdown: Workflow engine shutting down (interrupted? true)
[wf:7bb0cd58-7dc6-4a55-bb0f-62399533396c] OperationFailed: operation failed: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
SSH command execution error: Interrupted: Connection was interrupted
Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
Failed: Interrupted: Connection was interrupted
[workflow] finishExecuteNodeStep(mario): NodeDispatch: Interrupted: Connection was interrupted
1: Workflow step finished, result: Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [mario: Interrupted: Connection was interrupted + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(step:1, node:mario)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}, ContextView(node:mario)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}}, base=null)} ]
[workflow] Finish step: 1,NodeDispatch
[wf:7bb0cd58-7dc6-4a55-bb0f-62399533396c] Complete: Workflow complete: [Step{stepNum=1, label='null'}: CancellationException]
[wf:7bb0cd58-7dc6-4a55-bb0f-62399533396c] Cancellation while running step [1]
[workflow] Finish execution:  node-first: [Workflow result: , Node failures: {mario=[]}, status: failed]
[Workflow result: , Node failures: {mario=[]}, status: failed]
Execution failed: 57 in project iLAB: [Workflow result: , Node failures: {mario=[]}, status: failed]
```

It is just closing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck can't manage internal threads in that way (directly), with the kill button you can kill only the Rundeck job, the only way to manage that is by applying all the logic in your script (detect the thread, and depending on some option/behavior kill the thread). That was requested [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1038) and [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/3049).